# Download a File if it exists on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have this code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://MySite.com/Desktop/Pics.png"), 
    @"c:\users\Windows\desktop\DesktopsPics\Desktop.png");
```

My Program will download a `.png` picture every day as "Daily Pics" in a folder! So, when a user clicks on a button, if "Daily Pic" is already exists in server, the program will download this file.

I can do this with the above code, but, if `Pic.Png` is not already exists in server, my program throws an error. It downloads a `.html` file that reads `404 not found`.

How can I download a file, if this file exist on a server?

Comment: try/catch the exception that WebClient will throw when a 404 is encountered?

Comment: Use "HEAD" HTTP request before trying to Download

Comment: I think you are not using the right tool for the job here.  You should read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/17/downloading-a-google-map-to-local-file.aspx) for an example on how to use the `HttpClient` class to download a file where you can easily analyze the response to ensure a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are downloading the file Async, you will need to add an event handler for when the download is completed.  Then you can inspect the arg for errors.

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);

    string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"), fileName, fileName);

    Thread.Sleep(20000);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}

private static void DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
            // inspect error message for 404
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
        if (e.Error.InnerException != null)
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.InnerException.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        // We have a file - do something with it
        WebClient client = (WebClient)sender;

        // display the response header so we can learn
        foreach(string k in client.ResponseHeaders.AllKeys)
        {
            Console.Write(k);
            Console.WriteLine(": {0}", client.ResponseHeaders[k]);
        }

        // since we know it's a png, let rename it
        FileInfo temp = new FileInfo((string)e.UserState);
        string pngFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "DesktopPhoto.png");
        if (File.Exists(pngFileName))
            File.Delete(pngFileName);

        File.Move((string)e.UserState, pngFileName);  // move to where ever you want
        Process.Start(pngFileName);
    }

}
```